# Width of div and text the same and does not adjust with text length

Tags: html, css, list, text

I have this issue where it seems alright in JS fiddle but is having an issue in my html/css file:

**JSFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/0t4wxg29/

As you can see, I want the text to be under the div and not adjust with awkward gaps in between:

[image: 1]

But on my site, theres a gap created by the text:

[image: 2]

```
<div class="bubble">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>
        <div class="bubble-bg bg-1">
        <img src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/889-8891004_calling-girl-png-call-center-girl-png.png" />
        </div>
        </span>
        <p class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
        </p>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <span>
        <div class="bubble-bg bg-2">
        <img src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/889-8891004_calling-girl-png-call-center-girl-png.png" />
        </div>
        </span>
        <span> 
        <p class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
        </p>
        </span>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <span>
        <div class="bubble-bg bg-3">
        <img src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/889-8891004_calling-girl-png-call-center-girl-png.png" />
        </div>
        </span>
        <p class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
        </p>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <span>
        <div class="bubble-bg bg-4">
        <img src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/889-8891004_calling-girl-png-call-center-girl-png.png" />
        </div>
        </span>
        <p class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
        </p>
      </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bubble ul { 
  columns:4;
  list-style: none;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.bubble-bg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 20% 45% 45% 5%;
  background: #f5e511;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bubble-bg img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.desc {
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

Any reasons why the text does this?

My intention is to have the design looks like this:

[image: 3]

Any help would be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
.bubble li{
   margin:10px;
   
}
```

if you don't need margin top bottom ,release those points.